# Metrics using batches v/s metrics using full dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mobilenet, custom-training

I am using training an image classification model using the pre-trained mobile network. During training, I am seeing very high values (more than 70%) for Accuracy, Precision, Recall, and F1-score on both the training dataset and validation dataset.
[image]
[image]
[image]
For me, this is an indication that my model is learning fine.

**But when I checked these metrics on an Unbatched training and Unbatched Validation these metrics are very low. These are not even 1%.**

*Unbatched dataset means I am not taking calculating these metrics over batches and not taking the average of metrics to calculate the final metrics which is what Tensorflow/Keras does during model training. I am calculating these metrics on a full dataset in a single run*

[image]

I am unable to find out what is causing this Behaviour. Please help me understand what is causing this difference and how to ensure that results are consistent on both, i.e. a minor difference is acceptable.

Code that I used for evaluating metrics
My old code

```
def test_model(model, data, CLASSES, label_one_hot=True, average="micro", 
                threshold_analysis=False, thres_analysis_start_point=0.0, 
                thres_analysis_end_point=0.95, thres_step=0.05, classwise_analysis=False,
                produce_confusion_matrix=False):
    images_ds = data.map(lambda image, label: image)
    labels_ds = data.map(lambda image, label: label).unbatch()
    NUM_VALIDATION_IMAGES = count_data_items(tf_records_filenames=data)
    cm_correct_labels = next(iter(labels_ds.batch(NUM_VALIDATION_IMAGES))).numpy() # get everything as one batch
    if label_one_hot is True:
        cm_correct_labels = np.argmax(cm_correct_labels, axis=-1)
    cm_probabilities = model.predict(images_ds)
    cm_predictions = np.argmax(cm_probabilities, axis=-1)
    
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

    overall_score = f1_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=average)
    overall_precision = precision_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=average)
    overall_recall = recall_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=average)
    # cmat = (cmat.T / cmat.sum(axis=1)).T # normalized
    # print('f1 score: {:.3f}, precision: {:.3f}, recall: {:.3f}'.format(score, precision, recall))
    overall_test_results = {'overall_f1_score': overall_score, 'overall_precision':overall_precision, 'overall_recall':overall_recall}

    if classwise_analysis is True:
        
        label_index_dict = get_index_label_from_tf_record(dataset=data)
        label_index_dict = {k:v for k, v in sorted(list(label_index_dict.items()))}
        label_index_df = pd.DataFrame(label_index_dict, index=[0]).T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'class_ind', 0:'class_names'})
        # Class wise precision, recall and f1_score
        classwise_score = f1_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=None)
        classwise_precision = precision_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=None)
        classwise_recall = recall_score(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)), average=None)

        ind_class_count_df = class_ind_counter_from_tfrecord(data)
        ind_class_count_df = ind_class_count_df.merge(label_index_df, how='left', left_on='class_names', right_on='class_names')

        classwise_test_results = {'classwise_f1_score':classwise_score, 'classwise_precision':classwise_precision,
                        'classwise_recall':classwise_recall, 'class_names':CLASSES}
        classwise_test_results_df = pd.DataFrame(classwise_test_results)
    
        if produce_confusion_matrix is True:
            cmat = confusion_matrix(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)))
            return overall_test_results, classwise_test_results, cmat
        return overall_test_results, classwise_test_results
        
    if produce_confusion_matrix is True:
        cmat = confusion_matrix(cm_correct_labels, cm_predictions, labels=range(len(CLASSES)))
        return overall_test_results, cmat
    warnings.filterwarnings('always')
    return overall_test_results
```

Just to ensure that my model testing function is correct I write a newer version of code in TensorFlow.

```
def eval_model(y_true, y_pred):
  eval_results = {}
  unbatch_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='unbatch_accuracy')
  unbatch_recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='unbatch_recall')
  unbatch_precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='unbatch_precision')
  unbatch_f1_micro = tfa.metrics.F1Score(name='unbatch_f1_micro', num_classes=n_labels, average='micro')
  unbatch_f1_macro = tfa.metrics.F1Score(name='unbatch_f1_macro', num_classes=n_labels, average='macro')
  unbatch_accuracy.update_state(y_true, y_pred) 
  unbatch_recall.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
  unbatch_precision.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
  unbatch_f1_micro.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
  unbatch_f1_macro.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
  eval_results['unbatch_accuracy'] = unbatch_accuracy.result().numpy()
  eval_results['unbatch_recall'] = unbatch_recall.result().numpy()
  eval_results['unbatch_precision'] = unbatch_precision.result().numpy()
  eval_results['unbatch_f1_micro'] = unbatch_f1_micro.result().numpy()
  eval_results['unbatch_f1_macro'] = unbatch_f1_macro.result().numpy()
  unbatch_accuracy.reset_states()
  unbatch_recall.reset_states()
  unbatch_precision.reset_states()
  unbatch_f1_micro.reset_states()
  unbatch_f1_macro.reset_states()

  return eval_results
```

The results are nearly the same by using both of the functions.

Please suggest what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending many hours, I found the issue was due to the shuffle function. I was using the below function to shuffle, batch and prefetch the dataset.

```
def shuffle_batch_prefetch(dataset, prefetch_size=1, batch_size=16, 
                            shuffle_buffer_size=None,
                            drop_remainder=False, 
                            interleave_num_pcall=None):

    if shuffle_buffer_size is None:
        raise ValueError("shuffle_buffer_size can't be None")
    def shuffle_fn(ds):
         return ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size, seed=108)
    dataset = dataset.apply(shuffle_fn)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=drop_remainder)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=prefetch_size)
    return dataset
```

Part of the function that causes the problem

```
def shuffle_fn(ds):
    return ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size, seed=108)
dataset = dataset.apply(shuffle_fn)
```

I removed the shuffle part and metrics are back as per the expectation.
Function after removing the shuffle part

```
def shuffle_batch_prefetch(dataset, prefetch_size=1, batch_size=16, 
                           drop_remainder=False, 
                          interleave_num_pcall=None):
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=drop_remainder)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=prefetch_size)
    return dataset
```

Results after removing the shuffle part
[image]

I am still not able to understand why shuffling causes this error. Shuffling was the best practice to follow before training your data. Although, I have already shuffled training data during data read time so removing this was not a problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this sugesstion MAY help you, I am not sure. in this, you added

```
unbatch_accuracy.reset_states()
  unbatch_recall.reset_states()
  unbatch_precision.reset_states()
  unbatch_f1_micro.reset_states()
  unbatch_f1_macro.reset_states()
```

resetting states at each epoch maybe not be a cumulative one

Comment: as if you give input as batches. But it's questionable if y_pred, y_true is unbatched and given as single input

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have already used this as a part of my function. Even I tried this at the end of every epoch also. To confirm whether data is unbatched or not when inputting y_pred and y_true then yes it is unbatched. 
I doubt this part is problematic as if you look at the older version of code where resetting is not required but the results are more or less the same.

Comment: again in the older coding, you have done the one_hot encoding in the line one_hot_code is true. Am I crt? I think this may also cause such deviation.

Comment: thank you for helping in finding the solution. I figured out the problem was not due to the evaluation function but the problem was due to shuffling part of tf data.  Why it causes that error is still unknown to me but removing it solved my problem. Please let me know your views on this.

Comment: Thanks for such an interesting question. For the below shuffling problem as you have said, I looked at the importance of shuffling the dataset. shuffling the dataset, making the model more generic. If the shuffling cause the model to perform too low, the model is said to someway overfit. I am happy if the model works well. But if not, I request you to shuffle the dataset and then segregate the test and train dataset. I think this  MAY be helpful. If everything is fine please ignore this. :) thanks for posting such an interesting question

Comment: actually, I answered here because I don't have reputation for commenting.:)

Comment: Yes completely aligned with your views that shuffling is important. I shuffled the dataset during reading time and checked it post that and it is perfectly shuffled. This was an extra addon from my end. But again the part that I am not able to understand is why shuffling causes this behavior? I mean the learning behavior must be consistent with batch accuracy and unbatch accuracy with a slight difference. I think there might be something else that is going on with Shuffling. Maybe it is shuffling the image only and leaving the label unshuffle. This I will inspect